# How can I remove a Pine Script that appears on the bottom of every one of my TradingView Charts?

Tags: pine-script

I have the following script drawing in a panel on the bottom of my chart. How can I remove it permanently. I can close it temporarily, but when I reload the page, it's back. It appeart on any chart, no matter the currency or asset I am choosing.

(this is the indicator: https://www.tradingview.com/script/aFoIpKnh-FX-Currency-Strength-Indicator/)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the "x" here:

[image]

and then hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> to save your layout. You'll see the this layout icon:

[image]

change to:

[image]

Comment: Genious ! Thank You.